# How to come up with an example of a triangulation with two adjacent vertices of odd degree?

Tags: graph-theory, triangles, planar-graphs, triangulation

We define a triangulation as a planar graph with all faces(including the outer one) as triangles. What is an example of a triangulation with exactly two vertices of odd degree that are adjacent to each other? The number of vertices of even degree is unimportant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertices: A B C D E F G H I J K L

Edges: AB AC AD AE AL BE BF BG BL CD CH CL DE DH EF EH EI EJ EK FG FK GK GL HI HL IJ IL JK JL KL

The vertices A B H K are of odd degree, but A and B are the only vertices of odd degree that are adjacent.

[image: Graph]

If you allow only two vertices of odd degree in the whole graph, there is no such graph where they are adjacent.

Proof:

[image: PartGraph]

Let's assume the vertices A B C D are part of the *smallest* possible graph where A and B are the only vertices of odd degree. We remove vertex A and the edges AB AC, then we triangulate the graph by replacing the edge AD by the remaining even number of edges. So A disappeares, B turns even, C and D turn odd and all other verices' grades remain the same. So we have again exactly two adjacent vertices C and D in a *smaller* graph, which *contradicts* our assumption that our original graph were the *smallest* one.

Comment: Cool but I need graph with only two vertices of odd degree(this what I mean when write exactly two vertices).

Comment: @dasfex Such a graph does not exist. I added a proof.